# Activity accessing fragment's onCreateView's widget in onAttachFragment: NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my fragment, I have a search bar with a burger menu. When the latter is clicked, the navigation drawer must be opened. But it is defined in the activity.

To access the activity's drawer from my fragment:

1. I've created an interface containing the method `clickOnBurgerMenu`
2. In my activity, I have implemented this interface with a method that opens its drawer
3. In my activity, I have implemented the method `onAttachFragment` and here I call the fragment's method `setUpMaterialSearchBar`
4. In my fragment: in the method `setUpMaterialSearchBar(final ClickOnBurgerMenu activity)`: I call `activity.clickOnBurgerMenu();`

But the problem is that in the fragment's method `setUpMaterialSearchBar`, the call to `activity.clickOnBurgerMenu();` is executed in a listener set on the search bar. The latter being defined in the method `onCreateView` of this fragment.

So when the fragment is attached, the activity executes its `setUpMaterialSearchBar` method in order to set the listener with the activity's drawer, but the material search bar doesn't exist at this time: the listener is set on a `null` reference and a `NullPointerException` is thrown. In other words, more concretly: `material_search_bar` is defined only in `onCreateView`, called after the activity's `onAttachFragment` - that's the problem.

How could I solve this problem?

---

Sources

## The interface

```
public interface ClickOnMaterialSearchBarBurgerMenu {
    void clickOnMaterialSearchBarBurgerMenu();
}
```

## The activity (implementing this interface)

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
        HomeFragment home_fragment = (HomeFragment) fragment;
        home_fragment.setUpMaterialSearchBar(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void clickOnMaterialSearchBarBurgerMenu() {
    drawer_layout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
}
```

## The fragment (`material_search_bar` for example is defined only in `onCreateView`, called after the activity's `onAttachFragment` - that's the problem)

```
public void setUpMaterialSearchBar(final ClickOnMaterialSearchBarBurgerMenu activity) {
    material_search_bar.setOnSearchActionListener(new SimpleOnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
            switch (buttonCode){
                case MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_NAVIGATION:
                    activity.clickOnMaterialSearchBarBurgerMenu();
                    break;
                case MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_BACK:
                etc. etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to untangle your logic, you can introduce a

`private SimpleOnSearchActionListener sosActionListener;` in `HomeFragment`.

Change `setUpMaterialSearchBar()` as follows:

```
public void setUpMaterialSearchBar(final ClickOnMaterialSearchBarBurgerMenu activity) {
    sosActionListener = new SimpleOnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
            switch (buttonCode){
                case MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_NAVIGATION:
                    activity.clickOnMaterialSearchBarBurgerMenu();
                    break;
                case MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_BACK:
                // etc. etc. etc.
            }
        }
    };
    if (material_search_bar != null){
        material_search_bar.setOnSearchActionListener(sosActionListener);
    }
}
```

And modify `onCreateView()` by adding the following line after you initialise *material_search_bar*

```
material_search_bar.setOnSearchActionListener(sosActionListener);
```

Comment: Are the lines `   if (material_search_bar != null){
        material_search_bar.setOnSearchActionListener(sosActionListener);
    }` really useful and necessary?

Comment: @JarsOfJam - that depends on in which situations you want to call the method. In the situation which your question is about, you can omit these lines but keeping them won't hurt. If you want to use the same method later on (after onCreateView() has run), they are important