# Starting Fragment method from MainActivity causes Exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I work on an app which contains `Fragments` and a `ViewPager`. I fetch location data in my `MainActivity` and want to use it inside the fragments, so I created a method to pass the variables and process with them. Unfortunately I get a `NullPointerException` on all view objects, like the `progressBar` or the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside of the `Fragment` when the method is called. I guess the fragment is not correctly started just by calling a method, but how can I change it, so the view objects are created? Or is there another way to first fetch location data and use it inside the fragments afterwards?

My `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

private ViewPager viewPager;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

FragmentA FragmentA;
FragmentB FragmentB;
FragmentC FragmentC;
MenuItem prevMenuItem;

public double lat;
public double lon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_umkreis:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_karte:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_einstellungen:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });



    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            Log.d("page", "onPageSelected: "+position);
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    callsFragment = new CallsFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
    contactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();
    adapter.addFragment(callsFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(chatFragment);
    adapter.addFragment(contactsFragment);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    int limit = adapter.getCount();
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);
}

    public void start() {
        //Location data fetched here

        FragmentB fb = new FragmentB();
        fb.start(lat, lon);
    }

}
```

My `FragmentB`:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;

    String title;
    private BaseAdapter mItemsAdapter;

    private final List<HashMap<String, String>> mItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();


    public FragmentB() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list))
                .setAdapter(mItemsAdapter);


        return view;
    }


    public void start(double latGet, double lonGet){
        lat = latGet;
        lon = lonGet;

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }



    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        //Fetch And Process Data -> Result into resultList

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog

            final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
            AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appBar);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            //Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
            mItemsAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), mItemList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"brand", "price",
                    "dist", "street", "houseNumber", "postcode", "place"}, new int[]{R.id.brand,
                    R.id.price, R.id.dist, R.id.street, R.id.houseNumber, R.id.postCode, R.id.place});

            mItemList.addAll(resultList);
            mItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following method from `MainActivity`, you try to pass the location data to an instance of `FragmentB`:

```
public void start() {
    //Location data fetched here

    FragmentB fb = new FragmentB();
    fb.start(lat, lon);
}
```

The resulting crash is due to the fact that you only *instantiate* the `Fragment`, nothing else. Methods like `onCreateView()` or `onAttach()` will only be called if the `Fragment` is (about to be) added to the `View` hierarchy. So for this instance of `FragmentB`, methods like `getContext()` or `getActivity()` will return `null`. That's why you get `NullPointerException`s.

Make sure that you only call `start()` on a `Fragment` which has been added to the `View` hierarchy.  Or modify the method so that it stores the location data in some appropriate structure which can be accessed from e.g. `onViewCreated()`, `onStart()` or `onResume()`

See the docs for more [information on the `Fragment` lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle)

Comment: Okay, that’s good to know thank you so far! So to speak in reference to the `Fragment` lifecycle, the view methods can only be called after the `Fragment` is active and`onCreateView()` was completed? Would you be so nice and give me a hint how to handle it then? Is it only possible to do it by loading the variables in the `onCreateView()` of the `Fragment` or can it still be started in the `MainActivity`? Because the location fetch takes some time, how would I let the `Fragment`s `onCreateView()` wait until the location is fetched and stored if it‘s done that way?

Comment: @Mike Kng - IMO you do not need to delay showing FragmentB (and once you have called getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()........commit(), it's almost impossible / an extremely bad idea to try to delay the execution of e.g. onCreateView() - you might freeze the UI or even cause an app crash because of ANR). Usually one shows [some type of progress indicator](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html) so the users know that the app is still doing some background work.

Comment: The [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) describes how to load data in the background and register observers in a Fragment to be notified of data changes, maybe this is a good idea for your app

Comment: Okay, so the `onCreateView()` would wait through the fragment transaction? Like the transaction is executed after the data is fetched? But would that avoid the view hierarchy problem? So since I don‘t use fragment transactions to that point, do I need it to handle the issue, or can it be solved without transactions as well?

Comment: @Mike Kng - if you don't use transactions at all I suppose you only use the Fragments inside a ViewPager. In this case, you don't need to explicitly start a Fragment transaction because the ViewPager/ its adapter will do that under the hood. All the same, you can load data as soon as the app starts. You can also pass them into the Fragment. BUT you can only access Views if they have been inflated and you can only access the Context or the Activity in a Fragment if onCreateView() / onAttach() have been executed. So defer touching components until you can be sure they are really there.(cont)

Comment: (cont) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092048/activity-accessing-fragments-oncreateviews-widget-in-onattachfragment-nullpoi/55108625#55108625) is a similar problem where I tried to show how to pass in data (in this case a callback) but do null checks before accessing a View

Comment: @Mike Kng - one other thought: your code in start() is much abbreviated so this may be no "real" issue, but the instance of FragmentB which is created there seems not to be used in any way after you call fb.start(lat, long). So except for being involved in the crash it does not do anything (as far as I can see).

Comment: Is there a way to call onCreateView() from outside the fragment, so I could proceed with passing the variables and them access the view objects, or is the onCreateView only executed when the fragment is opened and started itself? I don‘t use the instance any further, I just use it to access the method. Is it a wrong way to do it like that?

Comment: @Mike Kng - "or is the onCreateView only executed when the fragment is opened ..."  yes, the Lifecycle methods should never be called by your code.

Comment: I get that I can’t access view objects then. So would it be the best way to store the location data in the MainActivity and access it then from the fragment? If so, is there a better way to store it for all accessable than a SQLite Database?

Comment: @Mike Kng - if it's not a large amount of data one can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) You can save the location data and use e.g. [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager) to let interested components know that there has been an update (A Fragment would have to register / unregister a corresponding BroadcastReceiver in onStart()/ onStop() )

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I‘m going to try it that way!